# Prove existence of Double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Prove
$\int\int_{Q} \left\lfloor x + y\right\rfloor\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ **exists** where $Q \equiv \left[0,2\right] \times \left[0,2\right]$.

I was trying to find some boundings for the function but IDK how to get to $\mbox{Sup}\ S = \mbox{Inf}\ T$ in order to prove the integrablity of the function.

Comment: I want  to prove that this integral exists

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gdmhoxt3h7) is a suggestion that will help you calculate the integral. The value of $\lfloor{x+y}\rfloor$ is constant in each of the colored regions I depicted in the hyperlink.

Comment: I want to first prove that this integral exists, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\left\lfloor x + y\right\rfloor
\dd x\,\dd y} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\left\lfloor x + y\right\rfloor\bracks{0 < x < 2}\bracks{0 < y < 2}
\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\bracks{0 < x - y < 2}\bracks{0 < y < 2}
\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\bracks{x - 2 < y < x}\bracks{0 < y < 2}\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\braces{%
\bracks{0 < x < 2}\int_{0}^{x}\dd y +
\bracks{0 < x - 2 < 2}\int_{x - 2}^{2}\dd y}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\braces{%
\bracks{0 < x < 2}x +
\bracks{2 < x < 4}\pars{4 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{2}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor x\,\dd x +
\int_{2}^{4}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \pars{4 - x}x\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\int_{1}^{2}x\,\dd x}_{\ds{3 \over 2}}\ +\
\underbrace{\int_{2}^{3}2\pars{4 - x}\,\dd x}_{\ds{3}}\ +\
\underbrace{\int_{3}^{4}3\pars{4 - x}\,\dd x}_{\ds{3 \over 2}}\ =\
\bbx{\large 6} \\ &
\end{align}